# Sprint boot json simple import failed

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I see spring boot has dependency list of json simple

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${simple-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I cannot import **org.json.JSONObject** inside my spring boot application.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: did you add the dependency in your project pom (without the version obviously )?

Comment: I tried to add json-simple inside my project pom (without version).   when I add it is saying dependency unknown.

Comment: check if maven has downloaded the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `org.json.simple` package.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

And reimport dependencies with your IDE's maven plugin.

Comment: Error - cannot resolve symbol simple. after org there is no json on import.

Comment: Which version of json-simple do you use?

Comment: latest version 1.1.1.

Comment: If you use Intellij IDEA press "Reimport all Maven projects" on maven tab. You need to force update maven dependencies in your IDE.

Comment: yes tried. no. I have elastic search jar files. will it affect ?. my iml file don't have the org.json

Comment: No, I don't think so. Problem only about that maven didn't download artifact. You can manually download it from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1 and add it as external library to your project.

Comment: Yes. but that is not proper way.

Comment: If it's not, you should figure out with your IDE's maven plugin, problem only with it.

Comment: yes. it failed to install. I tried with new project and it installed it. Now working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT*

> Although spring boot has a dependency on json-simple it's defined as
>   an optional dependency. So you need to add the dependency in your pom
>   as it will not be downloaded automatically with spring boot.

**Steps**

1. Add this to your pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
       <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Then Refresh dependencies running the command

   ```
   mvn package
   ```
3. Refresh/re-import project if you are using IDE(such as JetBrains
   Intellij Idea).
4. Import the Package in your class

   ```
   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
   ```
5. Use and Enjoy

   ```
   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
   public class Application {

       public static void main(String[] args)

           JSONObject.escape("");
           System.out.println("Done");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1''' dependency not found error.

Comment: Something wrong with your maven/project or you're not clicking the right place. That is the correct dependency version. Are you using a corporate nexus mirror or something?

Comment: @RoshanA is it possible to share your pom.xml?

Comment: by far the easiest